# Why are spree order numbers prefixed with R?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

In the spree [order model](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/core/app/models/spree/order.rb#L13) there is `include Spree::Core::NumberGenerator.new(prefix: 'R')` which makes all order numbers begin with R.

Is there any reason for this prefix and is it safe to drop it when importing orders in to an external system?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there would be any specific reason for numbering the orders with 'R'.
According to me, it's just for the convention.
You can drop this behavior while importing the order from external system as long as you are maintaining the uniqueness constraint on order numbers.